# What does this mean in this context ? もしかして、なりきってる残念な……じゃなくて本物のレイヤーか？ (MC did not believe that his favorite character in a mobile game is real)

Tags: meaning, japanese-to-english, conversations, video-games

**Context:** MC can't believe that his favorite character in the mobile game, which he has been playing, is real. He is going to buy a new smartphone in a smartphone shop, to replace his broken one and participate in a gacha event. Then he saw a cosplayer inside the shop, which is really looked like her, and he thought that's just a cosplayer working in the smartphone shop, which he went in to buy a new phone

> **"もしかして、なりきってる残念な……じゃなくて本物のレイヤーか？"**

Much thanks if anyone can explain to me the meaning of this sentence, and some grammar being used here o/

More context below:

> MC「ほ、ほんとにリリアさん？」
>
> Lilia「ちょうどマスターのスマホが壊れて、このままもうゲームをプレイしてくれないと思ったから……」(his favorite character in a mobile game (gacha?)
>
> まだ話してもいないのに壊れたスマホの事を知っているとはっ！
> もしかして、なりきってる残念な……じゃなくて本物のレイヤーか？
>
> その時、リリア（仮）さんが『マスター、まだ信じてないの？』とつぶやくと……
>
> リリアの体が白く輝き、展示台の上にあるスマホの画面に吸い込まれたっ！
>
> MC「Ｏ・Ｍ・Ｇ！」
>
> 吸い込まれたスマホに近づき画面を覗き込むと、その中に表示されているリリアが俺に向かって手を振っていた。

My guess but not sure based on context "If she's not her then it's unfortunate .... Then she's a cosplayer ?"

Answer (score 2):

Here 残念な means not "unfortunate" but something like "disappointing", "pathetic", "unsatisfactory", "poor" or "trying hard but useless". 残念な(人) in this context refers to an embarrassing/pathetic person who is behaving like Lilia.

> もしかして、なりきってる残念な(人)……じゃなくて本物のレイヤーか？
> Maybe she is not a (mere) pathetic person but a true (professional) cosplayer (behaving like Lilia)?

So MC initially thought she was just a strange person wearing a strange costume in a smartphone shop. Then he changed his mind and started to think she is a capable professional (because she spoke exactly like Lilia and even knew his smartphone was broken).

Comment: oh so he thinks that this girl might be a 残念な(人) ? Or 残念な(レイヤ) ? I'm not sure about the part he's about to say , but then changed his mind

Comment: @casualreader I don't think that makes any difference in this context.